# Show information after date PHP

Tags: php, date

I would like to show information after a date. I tried this, but now it will display when only the day is higher, and not the month.

```
<?php

        $datum = date("d-m-Y");
        $begindatum = '28-04-2018';

        if ($datum >= $begindatum)
        {
          echo "test";
        }
?>
```

Someone knows whats wrong?

Comment: It's for example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare between two dates in PHP, you have to change the date to `timestamp` first. To do that, check `strtotime()`.

```
<?php
$today = time();
$infodate = strtotime('28-04-2018');

if ($today >= $infodate) {
    echo "Information to show after 28-04-2018 goes here";
} else {
    echo "Information to show before 28-04-2018 goes here";
}
?>
```

Or use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php
$date['start'] = new DateTime();
$date['end'] = new DateTime('20-04-2018');

if ($date['start'] >= $date['end']) {
    echo "Information to show after 28-04-2018 goes here";
} else {
    echo "Information to show before 28-04-2018 goes here";
}
```

Comment: @J.Doe, Please do the green tick to mark it correct it answers your question.